# Как уменьшить расстояние между блоками?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Как уменьшить расстояние между блоками (расстояние указал красными стрелочками на картинке снизу) ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отрывок кода:

```
 <!-- Full Width Column -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="min-width: 990px; max-width: 1366px">

      <!-- Main content -->
      <section class="content">
      <!--left-->
<div class="col-sm-3">
...
</div><!--/left-->

<!--center-->
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
        ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!--/center-->

<!--right-->
<div class="col-sm-3">
...
</div><!--/right-->

      </section>
      <!-- /.content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
```

Comment: margin'ми наверное. Покажите код для начала, в котором вы не можете разобраться и что вы сами пробовали сделать.

Comment: добавил отрывок кода, смотрите

Comment: Нажмите F12 чтобы зайти в панель разработчка вашего браузера, найдите ваш Div и посмотрите его CSS. Если сами не поймете что делать, то добавьте его в пример, чтобы можно было что-то дельное посоветовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, вам надо что-то вот такое:

```
div.row {
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
div.container,
div[class^="col-"] {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо... практически работает... всё же решил остановиться на варианте getbootstrap.com/customize